# cntlm works for http but not https

Tags: proxy

I have installed and configured cntlm on a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit build (running in VirtualBox).

The Network Proxy setting is pointing to cntlm (`localhost:3128`) for both HTTP and HTTPS proxies.

Through Firefox, http URLs work, but https URLs are perpetually stuck trying to connect.

What's the deal?

Comment: do you mind sharing the conf file (minus the internal ip addresses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use the same port for both HTTP and HTTPS. Try changing HTTPS to a different port in Firefox and your cntlm configuration file.